# C programming - ld.exe cannot find - l - lwsock32

Tags: c, windows

I have done a little program,very simple, in C to manipulate IP addresses in a windows xp 32 bit computer, and the program works perfect. then i tried to debug it in a windows 7 64 bit computer and this message appears:

```
ld.exe cannot find - l - lwsock32
ld.exe cannot find - l - lws2_32
```

I linked `lws2_32` and `lwsock32` but it doesnt work. Does somebody knows if 64 bit windows is the problem?

Comment: Judging by the output, it seems you are not passing the options correctly. It should be something like `-lws2_32`, without any spaces

Comment: i tried writing it in so many ways and doesnt work. in xp, writing like this "-lwsock32" it`s ok